# Torroidal transformer design help needed

Tags: transformer

I have an idea for a simple circuit that I'd like to use to detect current flow in regular (US) AC household 120V, 60 Hz power.  All my electronics-making friends told me, of course, that there are numerous current sensing ICs on the market now, and that's true, but I'd like to pierce the veil of magnetics a little more myself.

Advice here on Stack Exchange was to go with a Rogowski coil and feed that to an integrator, which I started, then realized 1) Rogowski coils, when purchased, seem expensive, and 2) there isn't as much data about designing with them compared to torroids.

I would like to see if its possible to feed the line I'd like to monitor through the primary of a torroid, and feed the output of the primary to an op amp integrator.  I am at a loggerhead though.  So many engineering textbooks simply mention the very basic formulas for transformers, like ratio of turns in the primary to the secondary.  Few mention a design process using Al of the core, permeability, diameter, etc.  Also, I know an op amp is a very high gain device.  So what is a good level of voltage to shoot for to feed it in order to design around?  Or is that even the proper place to start?

In any datasheet, there is tons of information, and we find usually 2 or three of those parameters are the heavy hitters that frame the entire design, the rest usually are good for fine tuning.  With magnetics, I'm lost.  I need a kind of road map and a list of the parameters that are the important ones to start from.  I could grab a core, make a number of wraps, and see what I get and tweak from there, but I want do be able to eventually do some real engineering here.  Does anyone have any pointers or good books they can recommend?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you absolutely want to design it yourself from scratch, or buy a ready made current transformer?

Comment: What you are describing is a current transformer. Please read up and buy one before you connect anything self-made to mains. Even better, get yourself a LEM module or similar if it’s a one-off project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is with Rogowski Coils is that the design is very easy. If you do not care about high accuracy. The more windings the higher the output the better you can measure it. It will not saturate because there is no iron core. Take a plastic loop in the shape of a donut. It would be best if the donut has a small hole and a large outside diameter. Wire insulated copper around it in windings. The more turns you will make the higher the output signal. The two ends of the wire you hook up to an integrator circuit for integration of the signal and amplification. When complete put the to be measured wire/cable through the donut.

Count the number of turns you make the formula for calculating the current is:
$$
v_{(t)}={\frac{-AN\mu _{0}}{l}}{\frac {dI(t)}{dt}}
$$
found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogowski_coil#Formulae

It may be a lot of work and the accuracy is probably low but certainly possible.